# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I know this question was asked already multiple times and may be considered as duplicate. But I did not find an answer and decided to create new question.

The problem is ng-repeat doesn't work correct in Chrome, while it works fine in FF. There were couple suggestion in order to fix that but I already using them and it doesn't help.

1. One of the suggestions was to use array as a model in instead of object. 2. The second one was to use single quoted literal in order by.

I met both conditions and still see the problem in Chrome.

Here is my code:

```
<a  ng-click="pred = 'price'; reverse=!reverse">
    <span></span>
</a> | 
<a ng-click="pred = 'name'; reverse=!reverse">
    <span></span>
</a> | 
<a ng-click="pred = 'time'; reverse=!reverse">
    <span></span>
</a>
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:pred:!reverse">
</div>
```

Also there is link you can open in two browsers. There are items that are sorted by time (left column) they are sorted in FF but not in Chrome.

I am using angular 1.2.9 I think. Please advice how to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Reason might be you did not initialized reverse variable.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('orderByExample1', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.friends = [
      {name: 'John',   phone: '555-1212',  age: 10},
      {name: 'Mary',   phone: '555-9876',  age: 19},
      {name: 'Mike',   phone: '555-4321',  age: 21},
      {name: 'Adam',   phone: '555-5678',  age: 35},
      {name: 'Julie',  phone: '555-8765',  age: 29}
    ];
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="orderByExample1">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-init='reverse=false;'>
    <a  ng-click="pred = 'name'; reverse=!reverse">
    Name
</a> | 
<a ng-click="pred = 'phone'; reverse=!reverse">
    Phone
</a> | 
<a ng-click="pred = 'age'; reverse=!reverse">
    Age
</a>
  <table class="friends">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:pred:reverse">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
```